# Array in mysql or something similar

Tags: mysql, database

I have a question. I made this procedure, and I am curious if I can make it to return more than 1 output. Let me know if you need the tables, but the code is working only for 1 output for now. I want to return every single person who have that job and that gender.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS findPerson;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE findPerson(IN role_name VARCHAR(45),IN gen VARCHAR(10),OUT name VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
 SELECT Employees.Employee_Name into name 
 FROM Employees
 JOIN Roles
 ON Employees.Role_code=Roles.Role_code
 WHERE Employees.Gender_MFU=gen AND Roles.Role_Name=role_name;
 END |
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Don't use `INTO name`. Then the result set will be all the rows.

Comment: If you need to use this rowset in future query then you may: create temptable and transfer the data in it, aggregate the data to CSV string or JSON array and parse in outer code. If you simply need to retrieve rows from SP to your program like this is common SELECT then remove INTO clause.